# Why does ArcGIS Pro write a PDF file with some basemap images visible while other basemaps are not, depending on layout paper size?

Tags: arcgis-pro, pdf, layouts, basemap

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.5.1
The single layout in the aprx has four map frames, three small ones nested inside a large, whole-page map frame.  When I export to PDF (or to EPS, then Distiller to PDF) the result shows the basemap in the small map frames, but the large map frame does not have the basemap.  The basemap image that I am using in all of the map frames is Bing Maps Road.  In ArcGIS Pro it looks fine - all appropriate layers on checked On for visible.  However, when I check the layers (using Acrobat XI) the basemap layer for that data frame did not get written to the PDF, though the basemap is of course present and visible in the other data frames.

With more experimentation I see that it is explicitly about size.  If I lower the paper size of the layout from 158" to 140" then the basemap shows up.  However, last week I successfully produced some PDFs for maps that were 175" that had more map frames and similar amount of vector data.

[image: The image shows a sub-section of the ArcGIS Pro window in the bottom and the corresponding sub-section of the Acrobat results in the top. The small green rectangle at the top of the Acrobat section is a small map frame that does have its basemap. 'Pro shows the entire primary frame to have a white background.]

Comment: In my experience with ArcMap, if your image was coming from a wms service I'd say the provider has set a limit on image size which is good enough to use on your computer monitor but not enough for a larger layout.  see https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008899.  But I don't recall ever running into the limit using an ArcGIS online layer.  Are you getting your Bing maps from it or another server?

Answer (score 1):

[@johns comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367751/why-does-arcgis-pro-write-a-pdf-file-with-some-basemap-images-visible-while-othe#comment602217_367751) regarding the basemap source (WMS vs other) reminded me to try it at a lesser dpi.

Indeed, at 300 dpi the basemap got rejected, however at 150 dpi the basemap comes through fine.